# How to extract specific frames/model from a multi model pdb file?

Tags: proteins, pdb

I have a multi model pdb file and would like to extract the last frame or any other frame from it.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have access to [OpenBabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) to run from the terminal?

For the purpose of demonstration, the example following is demonstrated on a file listing SMILES strings.  However, *the concept* may be applied on a `.pdb` with multiple models (and equally works well enough on multi-model `.sdf`).

The input file `input.smi` is a small set of aromatics.  SMILES strings and labels are tabulator separated:

```
c1ccccc1    Compound 1
c1(cc(cc(c1)C)C)C   Compound 2
c1(ccc(cc1)C)C  Compound 3
c1(ccccc1)C Compound 4
n1ccccc1    Compound 5
n1cnccc1    Compound 6
n1cncnc1    Compound 7
```

My interest is on the *p*-xylene only (i.e., `Compound 3`).  With the instruction

```bash
obabel -ismi input.smi -f 3 -l 3 -osmi -O interest.smi
```

OpenBabel anticipates the input file to contain SMILES (`-ismi`), starts processing with the third model entry onward (`-f 3`, line/model counting index in the file starts by `1`), accessing all entries up *and including* the third one (`-l 3`) in this file.  The output, to contain SMILES and their labels (if present) is formatted (`-osmi`) and written permanently (`-O`) into file `interest.smi` which eventually contains

```bash
 c1(ccc(cc1)C)C  Compound 3
```

Since OpenBabel *run from CLI* is agnostic about file extensions, your processing of `.pdb` to be read, and to be written requires an adjustment of the input/output parameters e.g., in the pattern of

```bash
obabel -ipdb input.pdb -f 3 -l 3 -opdb -O interest.pdb
```

---

This approach equally allows to extract *a contiguous set* of entries, e.g.

```bash
obabel -ismi input.smi -f3 -l5 -osmi -O interest.smi
```

to process 3 molecules at once.  The toggles `-f` and `-l` may be used independently of each other, and spaces between them and their then mandatory integer parameters may be omitted.  The approach however is unable to pick a set molecules in the mixed pattern like `(1, 3-5, 7)`.

Said selection may be achieve from `obgui`, too:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
file=test.pdb #pdb file 
frame=10 # frame number to extract 
x_frame=$(egrep "MODEL.* $frame$" $file)
sed -n "/$x_frame/,/ENDMDL/p" $file > ${file::-4}_frame_$frame.pdb
```

output file will be written as filename_frame_10.pdb

---

The bash script below provides easier (repeated) access to the functionality described:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Extract a specific .pdb from a multi model .pdb file

# Save this bash script as pick_pdb.sh and run
#
# bash pick_pdb.sh test.pdb 3
#
# to write test_frame_3.pdb as new file.  Relies on bash and sed.

if [[ -z "$1" ]] ; then
    printf "Check how to use this bash script with
        bash pick_pdb.sh -h  \n"

elif [[ "$1" == "-h" || "$1" == "--help" ]] ; then
    printf "Export a specific model from multi model .pdb file.

E.g., to extract the third model from intput.pdb,

    bash pick_pdb.sh input.pdb 3

writes file input_frame_2.pdb.  \n"


else
    file="$1"
frame="$2"

    filebase="$(basename "$file" .pdb)"
    output=${filebase}_frame_$frame.pdb

    x_frame=$(egrep "MODEL.* $frame$" "$file")
    sed -n "/$x_frame/,/ENDMDL/p" "$file" > "$output"
fi
```

Comment: @Buttonwood could you please share the file?

Comment: thank you for catching this. I was grepping only ATOM section while babel has HETATM there. Removed the grep ATOM section.

Comment: Ok. Because I like your approach to call `sed` to extract *the* model of interest, a small re-usable bash script was written around your instructions. So autocomplete (of the file name) by the CLI and state the number of the model one is interested suffice. The repeated use *as such* (or, embedded into an other script past `chmod u+x pick_pdb.sh`) like `./pick_pdb.sh input.pdb 3` offer the results quickly with little typing only.

Comment: @Buttonwood , Fantastic :), thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python script *multiple_model_PDB_file_splitter*:

```
# multiple_model_PDB_file_splitter.py by Wayne Decatur
# ver 0.2
#
#*******************************************************************************
## PURPOSE: Takes a formatted pdb file with multiple models and splits each model
# into individual files. Requires the PDB file include both MODEL and ENDMDL


# records for each of the models.

# Originally developed in Python 2.7, but confirmed to work in Python 3.6.
#
```

You can download it from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/structurework/blob/master/python_scripts/multiple_model_PDB_file_splitter.py).

Other useful script from the same author can be download [here](https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/User:Wayne_Decatur/Code_for_Molecular_Structure_and_Visualization_Work).